# Changing dir to execute program in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to execute a program from a directory

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/user/a/b")
with cd("/home/user/a/b"):
    run ("./program")
```

i get cd is not defined...
any help appreciated cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what instructions you're following to get what you showed. There is no built-in function called `cd` or `run` in Python.

You can call a program in a specific directory using the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("./program", cwd="/home/user/a/b")
```

The `cwd` argument causes the `call` function to automatically switch to that directory before starting the program named in the first argument.

Comment: appreciate the speedy help :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use functionalities of fabric. Make sure fabric is installed, and cd and run are imported from fabric. Something like,

```
from fabric.context_managers import cd
from fabric.operations import run
import os
os.chdir("/home/user/a/b")
with cd("/home/user/a/b"):
    run ("./program")
```

Save your file as fabfile.py,and from the same directory run it as:

```
fab -H localhost
```

For more information on the fabric, checkout: [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/)